# How can I increment a variable using GTK4 Button?

Tags: rust, gtk

I have the following code excerpt:

```
let mut counter: u32 = 0;

button.connect_clicked(move |_|
    {
        counter+=1;
        flip_coin(&label)
    }
);
```

I want to increment the *counter* variable when I click the GTK4 button. How can I achieve this, since in the code excerpt I provided , `counter` is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to use the Cell class and to clone your element for it to be used inside the closure of the button.

Small example :

```
let counter = Rc::new(Cell::new(0));

button.connect_clicked(clone!(@strong counter => move |_| {
       counter.set(counter.get() + 1);
       println!("{}", counter.get());
}));
```

More details here: [Memory management with GTK4 and Rust](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/git/book/g_object_memory_management.html)